# How do I get sound to work outside lightdm

Tags: xorg, linux-mint, audio, lightdm, mutter

If for whatever reason I `sudo stop lightdm` running on mint and just use a simple xinit session with mutter, is there some way I can get sound to work?  Whenever I do that, it seems there's no sound.

Comment: Are you using `alsa`, `pulseaudio` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure your applications are using alsa output as opposed to pulseaudio or esd (Or start those daemons yourself). Also make sure your mixer is unmuted with alsamixer.

Comment: When I run alsamixer, I get "cannot open mixer: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue on Lubuntu 16.04 by installing `pulseaudio`:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```